# Problem with Addressable 1.8.5 not loading remote scene from AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, amazon-s3, addressables

**STACK:**

- macOS Catalina
- Unity 2020.1.8f1

**CONFIGURATION:**

I want to load a scene entirely from an AWS S3 bucket. I have followed two tutorials:

- Unity Learn: https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/addressables-scene-loading#5fadef93edbc2a07ae8db2a9
- MeowKim guide: https://gist.github.com/MeowKim/79796c1468872de6bf4b50f0bfb0ed41

I have a simple scene with a couple of buttons to press. In this case, the user presses "Load Remote Scene"

[image]

that will call the function to load the addressable (which uses a string to define the address). The function is trying to load the `Test_scene_2.unity` scene where there is a spinning cube.

[image]

A new "remote" profile has been created and set as `active`. Also, the remote AWS path has been configured:

[image]

As you can see I have an Addressable group that contains a reference to the scene:

[image]

And both global and group settings have been configured for generating a remote catalog:

[image]
[image]

As a final step, I have built the addressable group generating the `.hash`, `.bin` and `.bundle` files in the `AssetData` folder

**PROBLEM:**
I know that the next step is to load those files to the S3 buckets, but as reported in the MeowKim tutorial:

> "Running at this time would cause errors because Unity tries to get
> remote groups from the server."

Unfortunately, if I run the game in the editor and push the "Load remote Scene" button the scene gets loaded normally, which shouldn't happen because the S3 bucket is empty. I should get an error, which should disappear as soon as I upload the files. This means that my addressable assets are still pointing to the local files.

The strange thing is that if I build a standalone app the remote loading works, meaning it fails if the S3 bucket is empty but it loads the scene as soon as I load the addressable data.

In Summary:

1. Play in Editor: scene loads correctly with or without addressable data in the S3 bucket
2. Build and Run standalone app: everything works well (only if addressable data in S3 bucket).

What am I missing?

Comment: [Don't post images of your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)! Rather add it as **text** to your question, then format it using the `{ }` button

Comment: Added to the answer,
There is one way to test on Unity Editor when working with remote part. You can temporarily delete file scenes on your Unity Project. And you can test all the parts properly. It means when your remote storage is empty, the scene can not be loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had that problem,
I modified the scene's addressable keys to simple names without special characters and in one word, it worked for me
I hope this help someone.